# Showing that a total variation of a function is equal to some integral

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

I want to prove the same equality when g is jsut a real-valued 'Lesbegue' integrable function.
What is so frustrating here is that I can't use the upper sums or lower sums when g is just Lesbegegue integrable, not Riemann integrable.... Could anyone help me how to prove the above equality for Lesbegue integral cases?

Answer (score 1):

If $g$ is Lebesgue integrable then $f$ is absolutely continuous and there is a lot to work with.  For any partition $\{t_0,\ldots,t_n\}$ of $[a,b]$ you have
$$ |f(t_k) - f(t_{k-1})| = \left| \int_{t_{k-1}}^{t_k} g(x) \, dx \right| \le \int_{t_{k-1}}^{t_k} |g(x)| \, dx$$
so that $$\sum_{k=1}^n |f(t_k) - f(t_{k-1})| \le \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{t_{k-1}}^{t_k} |g(x)| \, dx = \int_a^b |g(x)| \, dx.$$
Now take the supremum over all partitions to get $\displaystyle Vf \le \int_a^b |g(x)| \, dx.$

The opposite inequality isn't too difficult but requires a little bit of the theory of BV functions. Have you seen the fact that if $f$ is AC (hence BV) then $f'$ is integrable and $$\int_a^b |f'(x)| \, dx \le Vf?$$
In your case $f' = g$ almost everywhere and that's what needed to be shown.

Comment: I know that the derivative of f is integrable, but what does the last inequality in your answer holds? Could you explain a bit more?